# Set a value in hidden null field in Chrome/IE11/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to set a value in subtext in JavaScript. Say Disptext has some value which I want to set in reportSubtext. This piece of code is working fine in IE8 but not in Chrome/IE11/Firefox.
I am getting error like can't set value of an object which is already null.
subtext is a hidden field. here is the definition of subtext :

```html
<input type="hidden" name="reportSubText" value=" c:out value='${reportSubText}' c:set var="reportSubText" value="${reportSubText}">
```

```js
document.getElementById('SubText').value = DispText
```

document.getElementById('SubText').value is null at the time of execution.

Comment: What is the html markup for the element SubText? My guess is you have a name and not an id.

Comment: What is the result of `document.getElementById('SubText')`? Does this element exist at the time you're running this piece of code?

Comment: Again, what is the HTML markup of the element you are trying to set. When are you calling it? The question needs more details.

Comment: document.getElementById('SubText').value is null at the time of execution. i am trying to set values in drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your answer and provide us with all the HTML.  From what I understand, you're trying to set values in a drop-down? The code below explains how to do that

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="list-1">
      <option id="opt-id-1" name="opt-1" value="val-1">Option 1</option>
      <option id="opt-id-2" name="opt-2" value="val-2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </body>

  <script>
    // first option (faster execution)
    var list = document.getElementById('list-1');
    var options = list.options;
    console.dir(options[0]);
    options[0].setAttribute('id', 'opt-id-1-CHANGED');
    options[0].setAttribute('name', 'opt-name-1-CHANGED');
    options[0].setAttribute('value', 'opt-value-1-CHANGED');
    options[0].innerHTML='Option 1 CHANGED';
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('SubText').value
```

This will return null as your code shows that the element does not have an id. You should try

```
document.getElementsByName('reportSubText')[0].value
```